# Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 Edition won't play video fullscreen

Tags: samsung, video, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

My galaxy note 10.1 (2014 edition) tablet used to be able to show netflix and youtube and other video links fullscreen. Now, the video quality drops dramatically and skips to black screens between some frames quite often. Some video streaming pages (the FIFA world cup website) will not even run fullscreen at all on my tablet. They go full screen, then stay black. Sometimes audio plays without video, sometimes nothing plays.

Is this a common issue? Is there an easy way to fix this? Or do I need to somehow have my tablet reloaded (where could I do this?)?